# how do i place a 4 * 6 image on a letter page at the top

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using imagemagick to convert files and reposition them, i have a 4 * 6 png which i need to position on a letter canvas on the top half of the page.

I have the below command which i am using, but its confusing. can anyone suggest how i can achieve what i want.

this is what i have tried, can any one guide me on this.

```
convert -rotate -270 -page Letter me-9370120111400937899958.png on-9370120111400937899958.pdf
```

I have also tried this, but the overlayed image is not moving and is stuck to the bottom

```
%x{convert -page Letter -rotate -270 "/var/folders/rp/rk2q4l7j4ds_w37vwvgx46tr0000gn/T/a8.png" -geometry +50+50 "/var/folders/rp/rk2q4l7j4ds_w37vwvgx46tr0000gn/T/a8.pdf"}
```

I have tried reading on this link http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry but could not figure out.

Comment: can the downvoter please explain the reason, i am trying and was confused hence i posted here, it something wrong in what i asked?

Comment: `imagemagick` may be on topic when you're including it in the context of some programming problem, but on its own like this it really belongs on superuser.com. And you haven't given enough information to determine exactly what problem you're having anyway.

Comment: "It's confusing" is not a very good problem statement. That's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It occurred to me later that you may have meant this:

```
convert -page letter -gravity north \( a.jpg -background yellow -splice 0x10 \)   a.pdf
```

Obviously change `yellow` to `none` and increase the `0x10` to `0x20` to move further down the page, and add `-rotate 90` before the splice maybe.

**Original Answer**

Not sure exactly what you mean, but I think this will get you started. Let's try some options. I will make the canvas yellow so you can see it and the file you want to position on top will be red.

So let's try some options...

First, let's move the image across to the right by zero pixels and down from the top-left by 40 pixels - the default position (or `gravity`) is NorthWest so we are positioning relative to that.

```
convert -size 612x792 xc:yellow a.jpg -geometry +0+40 -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

If you want the image centred, use `-gravity north` and position relative to that - a little closer to the edge this time maybe:

```
convert -size 612x792 xc:yellow -gravity north a.jpg -geometry +0+10 -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

If you want the background rotated:

```
convert -size 792x612 xc:yellow -gravity north a.jpg -geometry +0+40 -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

If you want just the overlay rotated, do that in *"aside processing"*:

```
convert -size 612x792 xc:yellow -gravity north \( a.jpg -rotate 90 \) -geometry +0+40 -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

If you want the canvas white, change `yellow` to `white`. If you want the canvas transparent, change `yellow` to `none`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, i think i can take it from here, thanks for the reply

Comment: Hello Mark, when i try your updated answer, i get a blank PDF. Can you suggest what could be going wrong. I have a image which i want to place on a letter page. May be i can explain better

Comment: I am trying this but the over lay image is sticking to bottom and not moving up %x{convert -page Letter -rotate -270 "/var/folders/rp/rk2q4l7j4ds_w37vwvgx46tr0000gn/T/a8.png" -geometry +50+50 "/var/folders/rp/rk2q4l7j4ds_w37vwvgx46tr0000gn/T/a8.pdf"}

Comment: `-gravity north` will move it up

Comment: Can you give me the dimensions of your PNG file, please, using `identify "/var/folders/rp/rk2q4l7j4ds_w37vwvgx46tr0000gn/T/a8.png"`

Comment: %x{convert -page Letter xc:white "a8.png" -geometry 1100x500 -rotate -90 -composite -quality 100  "b8.pdf"}, this moves the image to center, but  does not leave equal space on left. let me attach the image

Comment: i am unable to attach the image, i now have been able to overlay the image properly, but i want it to be centered where it is now. I am reallt sorry i am not able to explain it correctly. say now the image has som gap on the rite side but no gap on left. I want the rite and left gap to be equal

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks a lot i achived it using gravity center

Comment: i accepted your answer, as you helped a lot and atleast tried to explain me as much as you can, thanks a lot again, i am so happy

Comment: here is my final command with which i git it to work convert -page Letter xc:white file_path -geometry 1400x800 -rotate -90 -gravity center -composite -quality 100 file_path

Comment: Excellent - glad we got there in the end - sorry I couldn't get you there faster.

Comment: Awesome Mark you are a champion